# Is it possible to get warnings from compiler when replacing NSMutableDictionary with other class?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * dictionary = [[NSDictionary<NSString *, id> alloc] 
    initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];

// NS
NSMutableDictionary *  mutableDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[mutableDictionary setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

From various reasons, I need to change the class `NSMutableDictionary`,
to other custom class.

I've created a simple empty class, as follows:

```
@interface MutableDictionary2 :  NSObject
@end
@implementation MutableDictionary2 {
}
@end
```

and changed my original code, to use the new class:

```
// custom class
MutableDictionary2* mutableDictionary2 = [[MutableDictionary2 alloc] init];
[mutableDictionary2 setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

The desired behaviour, for me, is that the compiler will give me warning/error,
telling that `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` is not declared/defined in my new class, so I will have to implement it (with my new changes),
however I don't get any warning.

When I check definition of it, using IDE it directs me to:

```
NSKeyValueCoding::setValuesForKeysWithDictionary
```

And during runtime I get exception:

> "MutableDictionary2 setValue:forUndefinedKey :
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key key1."

Is there any way to get warnings/errors for this scenario ?
I prefer knowing about these problems when compiling, not running.

Different pattern ?

Compiler flag ?

"Trick" ?

Thanks for any help,

JD.

Comment: I don't believe you can, given the dynamic nature of the language.  One option is to make the classes implement a formal protocol and have non-optional methods in that protocol.  I think that will bring the compiler on-side.

Comment: your aim being to implement the method, or the aim being to find everywhere it's called? do you not know all the methods you need to implement on your new class?

Comment: Your class subclasses `NSObject` and therefore your expectation is not correct.

Comment: @Wain. Both. The codebase is huge, I need to implement all methods (only which are used) with some custom behaviour, but I don't know which methods of the class are used in the code. It might be possible to do it with some editor (e.g find all references, etc),  but I want it to be in code/compiler level.

Comment: what warnings do you get when you remove the superclass from your custom class ?

Answer (score 0):

`setValue:forKey:` and `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` are part of the informal protocol `NSKeyValueCoding`. Because it's informal it can only be checked at runtime, not compiletime.

If you want compiler warnings, you need to use different method names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all comments here, my solution was to change the base class of MutableDictionary2 from NSObject, to MyObject, where MyObject is defined as follows:

```
NS_ROOT_CLASS  
@ interface MyObject {}   
+ (instancetype)alloc;  
- (instancetype)init;   
@ end
```

This gives the desired warnings, and the class MyObject, can also be changed with #define to NSObject. Not the best solution, but its working.
Thanks for your help !